# Simplest way to read CSV file in a python function

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to run this script to read a .csv file in the same directory but I get the following errors upon execution:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\TEST\csvreader.py", line 11, in <module>
    csvReader('test.csv')
  File "C:\Users\Isaac\Desktop\TEST\csvreader.py", line 7, in csvReader
    for row in reader:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
>>>
```

## My Script Code

```
import csv 
 #Function for reading .csv file
    def csvReader(filename):
        with open(filename) as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter =' ')
        for row in reader:
            print(row[0])
    
    #Function that reads file
    csvReader('test.csv')
```

Comment: indent your for loop and the print statement inside the with open so you do not work on the closed file OUTSIDE of with open....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read from the `reader` object after the `with` block, at which time the file will be closed. A file that is opened using the `with` block will get closed on exiting the `with` block. Put your reader code inside the `with` block like below.

```
import csv 
 #Function for reading .csv file
def csvReader(filename):
    with open(filename) as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter =' ')
        for row in reader:
            print(row[0])

#Function that reads file
csvReader('test.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks! This took me a long while to figure out